# struggling with evaluationboard "WCH32v307v R1 1v0" right at the start

Tags: microcontroller, riscv, mcu

i newly ordered the named evaluation Board. I tried to setup the Blink example following the documentation, but uploading anything didnt work.
The Link Utility was able to connect and set the connection type to "riscv ch32v30x wch-linkrv".
I then tried to use the get information from the chip but the utility states:
Failed,the chip type is not matched or status of chip is wrong!

When trying to get something on the chip with arduino ide (libary installed of course):
Info : only one transport option; autoselect 'sdi'
Warn : Transport "sdi" was already selected
Ready for Remote Connections
Info : WCH-Link-CH549  mode:RV version 2.10
Error:  WCH-Link failed to connect with riscvchip
Error:  1.Make sure the two-line debug interface has been opened. If not, set board to boot mode then use ISP tool to open it
Error:  2.Please check your physical link connection
Error:  if your chip is CH32V00X,WCH-Link-CH549 does not support this chip, please use WCH-LinkE

Since im starting to do something like that, all of that is confusing, because in the wch documentation and on youtube, a wch link is used and it looks so easy. But my eval board has an usb c port intead of a link port.
Is there anyone that can help? Do i need to change something on the board?(btw: power led red, run led green, con led off)

Comment: Have you tried to ask ChatGPT it's great with such problems

Comment: yes chatgpt does not seem to be familiar with that exact model/problem/documentation, so it wasnt helpfull